# Black screen after login, but sound can still be heard on title screen

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, linux

I haven't played minecraft for probably over a year now and want to start playing some new mods and stuff, so I thought I'd start at the basics.

So I load up the game all normal and type in my details. Then a black screen appears. I leave it, thinking maybe it's doing some crazy new loading screen or something? But I can hear the menu buttons, like when you start a new world.

Any ideas what it could be? I don't know much about the technical side of Minecraft, so keep it simple.

I use Linux.

Comment: I'll ask the usual question, then. Are your graphic drivers up-to-date ? :D

Comment: umm i think i updated them, no clue, i have no clue what im doing when it comes to computer lmao, sorry haha but i have a crash report now, how can i post it? lol thanks for the help

Answer (score 3):

Due to the lack of detail, it's hard to say what exactly could be causing your problem. Minecraft should work just fine on Linux, assuming you are using the [Linux launcher](https://s3.amazonaws.com/Minecraft.Download/launcher/Minecraft.jar). You'll also need to download Oracle's JVM to get everything working properly. Assuming you've already done all of that, the game should work, but only if your computer can handle it. Minecraft is resource heavy and that's because it uses Java. You'll need to upgrade your drivers or get a better video card, but I find it odd that you can hear the menu buttons. That would definitely be indicative of some sort of graphics card error.

Comment: not gonna lie, i get confused very easily :3 but um, i think i have it all right, but what confuses me is i can play other games and i downloaded tekkit and can play it fine, well i could but now some reason i cant, i have a crash report on my minecraft now but not sure how to post lol, dont be mad, im just stupid with computers haha thanks for the reply :)

Comment: The crash report is probably massive. You could try pastebin

Comment: lol what do i do? never used it before, sorry

Comment: Go to http://pastebin.com/ and paste in your error code, give it a name, and press submit. Then share with us the URL for the paste.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/fwNx29pi

Comment: http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-1810956.html This is basically your problem but I don't expect you to understand any of it. It's basically a driver error assuming you have nVidia

Comment: lol yeah thats confusing me haha, not sure what to do lol

Comment: I wish I could help further but I don't have any experience with linux-based operating systems.

Answer (score 1):

Try re-downloading Minecraft and see if that works. Update your version of Linux and the graphics driver. Then restart and re-download.

Comment: dude i hate to say this, i have no clue how to do all them but the first one lmao, and yeah re-downloading didnt work :( but yeah i really am a noob to linux and confuses me, any way of you being able to post some links to help? sorry haha but thanks :)

Answer (score -2):

Your computer may be too slow to run so many mods.

Try un-installing your mods one by one and check which causes the problem. It might just be an out-dated mod. But still, if your computer is not the best it's probably that.

Comment: no mods, not possible, plus it cant be my computer as i used to run it perfectly fine, even with mods, this version is so basic, like its complete vanilla.

Comment: Capitalizing Every Word Is Rather Annoying.